# import file view on Mac El Capitan Not there

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

Not sure what this view is called but when importing a file from computer to the internet I no longer have this type of viewing option (see photo), is there way to have it appear this way?   [image]

Comment: Quicklook is the tool that generates finder previews. Are you downloading a file that when you select it in Finder and press space, no preview is generated? (Or is this more how to configure finder's controls to show a preview for a file that works when manually triggered?)

Comment: You are probably talking about the Open dialog here (which AFAIK doesn't have a CoverFlow option). Can you add a screenshot showing the problem (aka the window you see when you try to "import a file from computer to the internet")?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has removed Cover Flow view from Open file dialog.

As a workaround use a separate Finder window with Cover Flow view to locate your file in and then drag&drop the file into an open Open file dialog in your browser. The Open file dialog will then switch to the folder containing the file you dropped and highlight it.

Comment: Not that I ever use it, which is why I probably never noticed, but did that disappear with El Capitan?

Comment: Yes, in El Capitan. It seems like Apple is phasing out Cover Flow. They had a patent troll litigation about this technology a few years back, and Apple won. But since then Cover Flow has been removed from iTunes and now from Open file dialog.